# Run `head` on a text file inside a zipped archive without unpacking the archive

Tags: perl, parsing, shell, zip, etl

Greetings,

I've taken over from a prior team and writing ETL jobs which process csv files. I use a combination of shell scripts and perl on ubuntu. The csv files are huge; they arrive as zipped archives. Unzipped, many are more than 30Gb - yes, that's a G

Legacy process is a batch job running on cron that unzips each file entirely, reads and copies the first line of it into a config file, then re-zips the entire file. Some days this takes many many hours of processing time, for no benefit.

Can you suggest a method to only extract the first line (or first few lines) from each file inside a zipped archive, without fully unpacking the archives?

Comment: I know this isn't the answer but have faith, at least with gzip archives you can do it, even just vi will read into gzip. For gzip it's the programs zcat and zgrep, I don't know if those work with regular zip though.

Comment: Why does the job re-zip the file? Why can't it just use the original zip file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`unzip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) command line utility has a `-p` option which dumps a file to standard out.   Just pipe that into [`head`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head) and it'll not bother extracting the whole file to disk.

Alternatively, from [`perldoc IO::Compress::Zip`](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aCompress%3a%3aZip):

```
my ($status, $bufferRef);
my $member = $zip->memberNamed( 'xyz.txt' );
$member->desiredCompressionMethod( COMPRESSION_STORED );
$status = $member->rewindData();
die "error $status" unless $status == AZ_OK;
while ( ! $member->readIsDone() )
{
   ( $bufferRef, $status ) = $member->readChunk();
   die "error $status" if $status != AZ_OK && $status != AZ_STREAM_END;
   # do something with $bufferRef:
   print $$bufferRef;
}
$member->endRead();
```

Modify to suit, i.e. by iterating over the file list `$zip->memberNames()`, and only reading the first few lines.

Comment: `unzip -p filename.zip | head -1 >> headers.txt` works FLAWLESSLY thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Python's [`zipfile.ZipFile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) allows you to access archived files as streams via [`ZipFile.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open). From there you can process them as necessary.